# super.toString() or using attribute names

Tags: java

Lets say I have Person(String name) and Student(String name, String course) which extends Person.

What's considered better when Overriding toString() at Student?

```
return super.toString() + " course: " + course;
//or
return "name: " + name + " course: " + course;
```

Comment: Consider super.toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return super.toString() + " course: " + course;
```

Both the options are almost equally good. However first one is better design from maintainance perspective, consider scenario in future if you want to add new attribute to Person class say address. Then, you using first option you can avoid updating at two places. By option one, updating toString method of Person will add new attribute in Students toString also.

P.S. :- Consider using StringBuilder instead of concatenanting the string.

Comment: While downvoting, consider adding comments so that we can improve.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't matter much at all, but what it comes down to is what you want the relationship of Student and Person to be. If you want the `toString()` method of Student to always be `super.toString() + " course: " + course` so that when you modify the `toString()` of Person the `toString()` of Student changes, then sure that's the way to go. However, if you want the `toString()` of Student to be non-dependent on the `toString()` of Person then don't include a call to Super.

Answer (score 1):

In second method `super.toString()` is not good. Because `toString()` could return any other thing than `name`. First one will be better in your case. But it will not be any problem to use `super.toString()` as far as you are sure that it will return only `name` and will always be. But I will prefer to use first method.